# selecting an AMI for deploying a haskell app?

Tags: haskell, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yesod

I'm working on a haskell web app using yesod that I eventually want to deploy to EC2, can someone recommend an AMI that has a recent haskell platform and a git client install-able from the repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at Michael Snoyman's setup script here, it contains the steps he used to get an EC2 instance going on a Ubuntu AMI.

https://github.com/yesodweb/benchmarks/blob/master/setup.sh

I also have Yesod running from source on Amazon Linux. It takes a few hours to build everything but I think any of the standard boxes with at least 8G of memory should do it (otherwise GHC can't link).  This is how I did it:

```
# install what packages are available
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install haskell-platform git make ncurses-devel patch

# make and install ghc
wget http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.0.4/ghc-7.0.4-src.tar.bz2
tar jxf ghc-7.0.4-src.tar.bz2
rm ghc-7.0.4-src.tar.bz2
cd ghc-7.0.4
./configure
make -j 4
# wait a few hours
sudo make install
cd
rm -rf ghc-7.0.4

# make and install haskell-platform
wget http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/download/2011.4.0.0/haskell-platform-2011.4.0.0.tar.gz
tar zxf haskell-platform-2011.4.0.0.tar.gz
cd haskell-platform-2011.4.0.0
./configure
make -j 4
sudo make install
cd
rm -rf haskell-platform-2011.4.0.0
```

Comment: What about the standard Amazon Linux AMI?

Comment: The above script is for the Amazon Linux AMI, as of February. I haven't tried it lately so please update us if any tweaks are necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you're building by hand instead of `yum install haskell-platform`ing?

Comment: @amindfv It wasn't available even on the epel at the time. If it is now, then I would certainly try that route. Building haskell-platform takes hours.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't compile on an EC2 instance. Choose a generic AMI like Ubuntu, and perform the compile on a local computer, then upload the static binary to EC2.

Comment: How do you know if what you compiled locally, will run on EC2? Do you have to have identical image/snapshot of Ubuntu?

Comment: No, if you compile for Linux x86_64, it should run on any distribution of Linux that is 64-bit, but you might have to install some extra libraries with the instance's package manager.